can you help me fix a problem with my javascript code which is how to check if a key was pressed
i want to check if a key was pressed to make something pop up
i tried to make a text box but it wasn't secret enough. so can you make it work please
so if i pressed P it would pop up with something eg:"the password is 'blah blah blah'"

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

To detect if a specific key was pressed and trigger an event in JavaScript, you can use the keydown event listener.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Key Press Event</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;background-color:lightyellow;padding:10px;border:1px solid black;">
        The password is '12345678'
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            if (event.key === 'P' || event.key === 'p') {
                const messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
                messageDiv.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

